# What does $('#id').html(x) do differently to el.innerHTML = x

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm storing stuff in javascript/DOM and submitting an ajax call. In the success and/or .done function when I do:

```
$('#results').html(data);
```

The javascript/DOM model becomes corrupted but when I do:

```
var el = document.getElementById('results');
el.innerHTML = data;
```

then everything works as expected. I know there isn't much information here but my question is what else is the jQuery html() doing apart from setting the innerHTML that may be effecting the state of the page.

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: How does it become "corrupted"?

Comment: I have a maphilight image map on the screen (not within the results div) and the set of areas with alwaysOn set of true seems to change and the selecting area mechanism stops working.

Comment: @DavidNewcomb: To improve/clarify the question, use the "edit" link.

Comment: Can you build a fiddle ?

Answer (score 4):

The main reason to use the `html` function with a string rather than `innerHTML` is to prevent memory leaks or inconsistent in memory data : this function removes event handlers or other jQuery data linked to the removed elements.

If `data` is a string, there is no reason for `$('#results').html(data);` to "corrupt" your DOM more than by using `innerHTML`.

Comment: data is some HTML code. According to FireBug the data comes back as normal in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

In Internet Explorer 9 and earlier tables in the DOM were read-only. That meant that trying to do `el.innerHTML = newHTML;` would result in an error being thrown if `el` was a TBODY, TR, etc. The jQuery `.html()` function handles that case for you by using a fallback method - `this.empty().append(value)` in the jQuery source - allowing you to use the same code for all of the browsers, regardless of version.

It may be worth taking a look at the code for the method in the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js):

```
html : function (value) {
    return jQuery.access(this, function (value) {
        var elem = this[0] || {},
        i = 0,
        l = this.length;

        if (value === undefined) {
            return elem.nodeType === 1 ?
            elem.innerHTML.replace(rinlinejQuery, "") :
            undefined;
        }

        // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
        if (typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test(value) &&
            (jQuery.support.htmlSerialize || !rnoshimcache.test(value)) &&
            (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test(value)) &&
            !wrapMap[(rtagName.exec(value) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase()]) {

            value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

            try {
                for (; i < l; i++) {
                    // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                    elem = this[i] || {};
                    if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
                        jQuery.cleanData(getAll(elem, false));
                        elem.innerHTML = value;
                    }
                }

                elem = 0;

                // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        if (elem) {
            this.empty().append(value);
        }
    }, null, value, arguments.length);
}
```